# Electron App ReferenceError: "package" is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I'm trying to port my webapp into a desktop app. I'm trying to use electron. I have basically created the package.json, main.js and ran the `electron .` command. Everything seems ok, but I get an error saying in this case

> ReferenceError: Flow is not defined

I'm using ng-flow.

It works fine if I just open it on WebBrowser and other packages imported doesn't seem to have a problem. 
Is there some considerations I should take into account when developing electron app regarding the packages I import?

> script src="..."

Comment: Which are lines of code showing the error? Could you share package.json file for more information.

Comment: can you add what you have to github perhaps? it will be easier to see what your config etc. looks like...

Answer (score 0):

It depends which file you're importing the script from.

if it's from the HTML page you need to be import if using the relative path for example:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
```